# Observableのエラー発生以降にnext()が機能しなくなる。

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2, rx-javascript

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

上記チュートリアルに従いObservableにてhttp処理を実装しています。

```
this.heroes = this.searchTerms
  .debounceTime(300)        // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
  .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
  .switchMap(term => term   // switch to new observable each time the term changes
    // return the http search observable
    ? this.heroSearchService.search(term)
    // or the observable of empty heroes if there was no search term
    : Observable.of<Hero[]>([]))
  .catch(error => {
    // TODO: add real error handling
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.of<Hero[]>([]);
  });`

・・・

    this.searchTerms.next(term);
```

しかしながらここで1回でもhttpエラーが発生すると(上記のcatchのルートに入ると)、
以降nextをコールしてもデータが流れていきません。

ユーザーにしばらく待ったのち再トライすることを促し、もう一度SubmitさせるようなUIにしたいのですが、
エラーをハンドル(onError()をコール)しつつ、エラー発生後もストリーミングを止めない方法はありますでしょうか？

---

**追記：**

[こちらの記事](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649652/rxjs-catch-error-and-continue)を参考に
下記の様にerrorが発生し得る処理のcatchをswitchMap()の中に入れ子にすることによってエラーが発生してもnextに空配列が渡されるようにはなりました。
※SOenを見ると"flatMap()を使えば良い"とflatMap()に限定した記事をよく見ますが、
　Observable内の輻輳制御の仕様次第かと思いますので、
　用途に応じswitchMap/flatMap/mergeMapどれでも良い理解ですが誤りあればご指摘ください。

```
this.heroes = this.searchTerms
  .debounceTime(300)        // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
  .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
  .switchMap(term => term   // switch to new observable each time the term changes
    // return the http search observable
    ? this.heroSearchService.search(term)
          .catch(error => {
            // TODO: add real error handling
            console.log(error);//ここには来る
            return Observable.of<Hero[]>([]);
          })
    // or the observable of empty heroes if there was no search term
    : Observable.of<Hero[]>([]));
//確認用コード
this.heroes.subscribe(res=>{
              console.log("next");//エラー時もここには来る(Hero[]が返る)
              return res;
            },
            err=>{
              console.log("err");//ここに来ない
            })
```

しかしながら目的動作は「subscribe.onError()をコールしてもらいつつ、エラー時に受付を止めたくない」となります。
前述した記事に関してもonError()はコールされておらず、入れ子にしたcatchがコールされるのみでした。

(Observableのストリーミングの一部をUtilクラスに内包しており、使用者側にObservableを返すような作りにしているので、ストリーミング内のエラーが発生し得る処理ひとつひとつのcatchを使用者側に課したくなく、あくまでsubscribeで結果を通知したいためです。)

Comment: error/completeが発生するとストリームは殺されるので一旦別のObservableで受けるという[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827371/how-do-i-throw-an-error-on-a-behaviour-subject-and-continue-the-stream)、`flatMap`を使用してエラーを受ける内部のObservableを作成するという[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649652/rxjs-catch-error-and-continue)。どちらもObservableでの実装の話でSubjectでも同様にできるかわかりませんが、興味があるので試してみてぜひ結果を共有してもらいたいです。

Comment: flatMapは(私のimportが悪いだけだと思うので見直しますが)エラーがでてしまったのでまだ試していないのですが、二つ目の記事のポイントはエラーが起きうる処理をObservableの入れ子にする点であると理解し、上記のhttp処理(serach())をそのままswitchMapの入れ子にしたところうまく行きました。ただ他の記事を見ても「flatMap()を使用して」、というのをよく見ます。flatMap()でなければいけない理由等わかりますでしょうか。

Comment: 「エラーハンドリング」の定義が曖昧でしたので「subscribe.onError()」を追記しました。

Comment: コメント遅くなりすみません。すでに質問に追記されていますが、[flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)は非同期的、switchMapは同期的にObservableを処理します。switchMapはRxJS4以前ではflatMapLatestのことです。(個人的にはこの名称の方が意味が掴みやすかったです)

Comment: 追記された部分についてですが、先のコメントにも書いたようにerror/completeが発生するとストリームがkillされるというのがObservableの基本思想なので出来ないのではないでしょうか。呼び元にはObservableで返さずに、「subscribeで吸収し呼び元にonNext、onErrorを返す」ような独自のObservableっぽい内部処理を用意するしかなさそうです。すみません試せていませんので、回答ではなくコメントにしています。